# Non-symmetrical parabola

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

Sorry if this is a really simple question, but I was looking for an equation to produce a non-symmetrical parabola. (The left side of the parabola would have a different 'slope' than the right side of the parabola)

Thanks!

**Edit:** If I clarify the purpose of this, it may help people understand my problem better. I'm trying to make a physics engine for a game, where the character can jump. The parabola-shape will represent the jump arc - it takes more time to jump up (to the vertex) than it does to fall down (to the x-intercept). Because of this, I'd like the y-intercept and first x-intercept to be at the origin, and move up from there.

Comment: Every parabola is symmetrical. Whatever you are looking for, it's not a parabola.

Comment: Could you try and describe more accurately what you are looking for?

Comment: Something like $y=(2x-|x|)^2$?

Comment: @mathlove that seems to work, but I'd like to move it beyond where the vertex is 0.

Answer (score 5):

You can stitch a Frankenbola together like this.
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
a_l x^2 + b_l x + c_l & \text{for } x < 0 \\
a_r x^2 + b_r x + c_r & \text{for } x > 0 \\
c & \text{for } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
You can require continuity for $f$ then you get
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
a_l x^2 + b_l x + c & \text{for } x < 0 \\
a_r x^2 + b_r x + c & \text{for } x > 0 \\
c & \text{for } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
However your derivative looks like
$$
f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
2 a_l x + b_l & \text{for } x < 0 \\
2 a_r x + b_r & \text{for } x > 0 \\
b & \text{for } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
You can ask for continuity for $f'$ too and get
$$
f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
2 a_l x + b & \text{for } x < 0 \\
2 a_r x + b & \text{for } x > 0 \\
b & \text{for } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Which gives you this $f''$:
$$
f''(x) =
\begin{cases}
2 a_l & \text{for } x < 0 \\
2 a_r & \text{for } x > 0 \\
a & \text{for } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
You could require continuity again, but then you end up with a symmetrical parabola.

So it is up to you where to give up continuity.

Comment: I like the name Frankenbola, but I'm not sure I'd like to meet one.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going assume that you mean symmetric along a fixed $x$ value.

What you can do to construct a parabola which does not have that is to start with one which has one and then apply a rotation of all points in the plane. Basically exchanging the old x and y coordinates with new ones according to the rotation:

$$x_{old} = \cos(\phi)x_{new} + \sin(\phi)y_{new}$$
$$y_{old} = -\sin(\phi)x_{new} + \cos(\phi)y_{new}$$

So if the initial parabola is

$$y_{old} = (x_{old}-c)^2$$

you can just plug in the above and simplify to see what you get. It will be an equation involving $y_{new}$, $x_{new}$ and their squares and stuff.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need something skew, looking roughly like a parabola, you could use higher polynomials: y(x) = $x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2$, or with other coefficients.

Comment: This appears to work best so far: do you know what variables I need to manipulate to make the right side of the parabola have a steeper 'slope' than the left side but otherwise smooth?

Comment: Actually when the coefficient from $x^3$ is positive it should be like that. For example look at: $0.001 x^4+0.01 x^3+x^2 $, say at -10 < x < 10, then compare to $0.001 x^4+0.02 x^3+x^2 $, thats then already steeper. You don't have to bother about continuity they are everywhere continuous. Just they are not really parabolas, but anyway look very similar. You need the positive quartic term, otherwise it gets rather a "S"-shape than an "U"-shape.

Comment: But when you restrict to some closed interval you could even drop the quartic term.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a function whose parts are all parabolas but the resulting graph will not be a parabola. For example:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^{2} &\text{if}\,\,x\le 0\\
2x^{2} &\text{if}\,\, x> 0
\end{cases}$$

In a more general way, you can define

$$p(x)=\sum_{i}\left(\mathbb{I}_{[a_{i},b_{i})}(x)\right)(\alpha_{i} x^{2}+\beta_{i})$$
where 
$$\mathbb{I}_{[a_{i},b_{i})}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if}\,\,x\in [a_{i},b_{i})\\
0 &\text{if}\,\,x\notin [a_{i},b_{i})
\end{cases}$$
and $[a_{i},b_{i})\cap[a_{j}, b_{j})=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$.
By taking successively distinct $\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}$, you'll have a function whose parts are all parts of some parabola, but its graph will not be one.